# Discarding Coins in Splendor

Tags: splendor

In Splendor there is a max coin limit of 10. If I exceed that limit by one, Would I need to return the most recently acquired coins, or could I return any in my hoard?

The rules:

> A player can never have more than 10 tokens at the end of
>   their turn (including jokers). If this happens, they must return
>   tokens until they only have 10 left. A player can return all or
>   some of those they’ve just drawn.

Answer (score 4):

You may return any of your tokens. The wording in the rules just confirms that the tokens you return can include any of the ones you just took.